# No me ejecuta la consulta mysql en php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando ejecutar esta consulta y mostrar mi lista de usuarios por código:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connectiondb "SELECT * FROM players,codes WHERE (players.code = codes.c_code) AND NOT (players.unique_id = {$outgoing_id})");
```

Alguno sabe porqué no funciona?. Si pongo otras consultas va bien y si la misma la llevo a phpMyAdmin, pasándole un unique_id, me muestra las filas necesarias.

Comment: En principio, falta una coma en `db "SELECT`, debería ser  `db, "SELECT` Si no es eso, deberías aportarnos algo más de información para poder ayudarte

Comment: ¿Que error te aparece?¿El sitio se congela?¿Tienes logger o manejo de excepciones ?